# Take out elements from a vector that meets certain condition

Tags: performance, matlab, vector, vectorization

I have two vectors, `A = [1,3,5]` and `B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. I want to get `C=[2,4,6,7,8,9,10]` by extracting some elements from `B` that `A` doesn't have.

I don't want to use loops, because this is a simplified problem from a real data simulation. In the real case `A` and `B` are huge, but `A` is included in `B`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are two methods,

```
C=setdiff(B,A)
```

but if values are repeated in `B` they will only come up once in `C`, or

```
C=B(~ismember(B,A))
```

which will preserve repeated values in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach with `unique`, `sort` and `diff` -

```
C = [A B];

[~,~,idC] = unique(C);
[sidC,id_idC] = sort(idC);

start_id = id_idC(diff([0 sidC])==1);
out =  C(start_id(start_id>numel(A)))
```

Sample runs -

Case #1 (Sample from question):

```
A =
     1     3     5
B =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
out =
     2     4     6     7     8     9    10
```

Case #2 (Bit more generic case):

```
A =
    11    15    14
B =
    19    14     6     8     9    11    15
out =
     6     8     9    19
```

Comment: I have tried to use index to do same thing, but I failed. Thanks for your code.

Comment: @meng I think if there are duplicates within the input arrays themselves, it won't work.